# I need to remove the video in the background by pressing the button JS

Tags: javascript

I have a video in the background that is always on. But I want to make it possible to disable it to reduce the load on the pc. How to do it using JavaScript. I tried to make opacity 0 but I think video is still playing and makes an extra load. Sry for my English

```js
const backVideo = document.querySelector("video");
var videoButton = document.getElementById("VideoOf")
var videoButtonOn = document.getElementById("VideoOn")

function videoOf() {
  backVideo.style.opacity = "0"
  if (backVideo.style.opacity = "0"){
    videoButton.style.opacity = "0"
    videoButtonOn.style.opacity = "1"
    
  } 
}
function videoOn() {
  backVideo.style.opacity = "1"
  if(backVideo.style.opacity = "1"){
    videoButtonOn != null;
    videoButton.style.opacity = "1"
    videoButtonOn.style.opacity = "0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the video API have a `video.stop()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have for example this type code:

```
<video width="500" height="300" autoplay muted loop id="video">
      <source src="example.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

You basically can remove here the source part by default, then add it after page loaded.

So by default:

```
<video width="500" height="300" autoplay muted loop id="video">
      
</video>
```

Script :

```
function videoOn() {
document.getElementById('video').innerHTML=
'<source src="example.mp4" type="video/mp4">';
}
```

I just showed you how it can be done easily. Of course, it can be written in a nice form by using the element creation and attribute functions more properly.